# How to get a user id from table using hibernate

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc

I am trying to get a single value from a table but got errors on there

Let me consider one simple sql syntax.

---

> select id from tbl_name where email = 'abc@gmail.com';

Now i want a method that returns a user id using hibernate

here is what i have tried so far

```
public int getIdByEmail(String email) {
    session = sessionFact.openSession();
    Query query = session.createQuery("SELECT u.user_id FROM tbl_user u WHERE u.email=:emailParam");
    query.setParameter("emailParam", email);
    return (int) query.uniqueResult();
}
```

**User.java**

```
    @Entity
@Table(name = "tbl_user", catalog = "lifestyle", schema = "")
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "User.findAll", query = "SELECT u FROM User u")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "User.findByUserId", query = "SELECT u FROM User u WHERE u.userId = :userId")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "User.findByFullName", query = "SELECT u FROM User u WHERE u.fullName = :fullName")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "User.findByAddress", query = "SELECT u FROM User u WHERE u.address = :address")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "User.findByContact", query = "SELECT u FROM User u WHERE u.contact = :contact")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "User.findByGender", query = "SELECT u FROM User u WHERE u.gender = :gender")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "User.findByDob", query = "SELECT u FROM User u WHERE u.dob = :dob")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "User.findByEmail", query = "SELECT u FROM User u WHERE u.email = :email")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "User.findByPassword", query = "SELECT u FROM User u WHERE u.password = :password")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "User.findByActive", query = "SELECT u FROM User u WHERE u.active = :active")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "User.findByCreatedDate", query = "SELECT u FROM User u WHERE u.createdDate = :createdDate")})
public class User implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)

    @Column(name = "user_id")
    private Integer userId;

    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 256)
    @Column(name = "full_name")
    private String fullName;
    @Size(max = 256)
    @Column(name = "address")
    private String address;
    @Size(max = 30)
    @Column(name = "contact")
    private String contact;
    @Size(max = 10)
    @Column(name = "gender")
    private String gender;
    @Column(name = "dob")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date dob;
    // @Pattern(regexp="[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?", message="Invalid email")//if the field contains email address consider using this annotation to enforce field validation

    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 256)
    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email;

    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 256)
    @Column(name = "password")
    private String password;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "active", insertable = false)
    private short active;
    @Column(name = "created_date", insertable = false)
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date createdDate;
```

Error is
[image]

Comment: what it return ?

Comment: @JohnJoe - shows me an error

Comment: And why use the deprecated, proprietary criteria API to do that instead of a dead simple, standard JPQL query?

Comment: @NishanDhungana we can't tell you why an error is being generated if you don't post the error. An error comes with a type, a message and a stack trace. They're all meant to be read, and all give precious indications on what is wrong.

Comment: @JBNizet - I have updated my question please have a look

Comment: OK. Now read it. It's plain english: "could not resolve property user_id of User". That means User doesn't have any property named user_id. Use the correct property name.

Comment: @JBNizet-user_id is same as User

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162069/discussion-between-nishan-dhungana-and-jb-nizet).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to use entity names and properties in the query, not the table and column names. So the below query:

> Query query = session.createQuery("SELECT u.user_id FROM tbl_user u
>   WHERE u.email=:emailParam");

should be

> Query query = session.createQuery("SELECT u.userId FROM User u WHERE
>   u.email=:emailParam");

Comment: I think you are using `SELECT u.user_id...` but it should be `SELECT u.userId...`. The property name in the user entity.